# Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn how to use DAO and BO classes and I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/database/Hibernate.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'annotatedClasses' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'annotatedClasses' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Hibernate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<!--class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">-->
<property name="dataSource">
  <ref bean="dataSource"/>
</property>

<property name="configLocation">    
    <value>classpath:spring/database/hibernate.cfg.xml
    </value>
</property>

<property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
     <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
</property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
<list>
    <value>com.fexco.helloworld.web.model.Customer</value>
    <value>com.fexco.helloworld.web.model.Countries</value>
</list>
</property>

</bean>
```

DataSource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean 
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location">
    <value>/properties/database.properties</value>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" 
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
<property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
<property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
<property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>


 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="data" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I dont know where the error is coming from as my getter and setter methods in my countries.java and customer.java classes are all correct!

Does anybody know whats going wrong? (if you need to see any of the other classes just add a comment saying which classes and il post them up)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually complaining about the `annotatedClasses` property of the session factory, you are using a `LocalSessionFactoryBean` that doesn't have it (you have commented out `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` that *does* have it).

Comment: ah ya, i was messing around with it earlier when it was working and changed that and never changed it back... cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to set "annotatedClasses" property originally coming from AnnotationSessionFactoryBean while you are actually using LocalSessionFactoryBean that does not have this property.